# next auto increment of table at DB with php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the next auto increment id with PHP. I run the query in mysql and need the result:

```
column name: auto_increment value = 122
```

but I am getting a Notice:

> Trying to get property 'auto_increment' of non-object

```
public function findNextAutoIncrementId()
    {
        $db = config::getConnexion();
        $sql = 'SELECT `auto_increment` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE table_name = newsarticle';
        $req = $db->prepare($sql);
        $req->execute();
        $result = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $result;
    }
// when i use it i get  Notice: Trying to get property 'auto_increment' of non-object
$result=$sujetC->findNextAutoIncrementId();
echo "this is : ".$result->auto_increment;
```

[Edit] : When I asked this question I wanted to find the next 'newsarticle' object that will be created to do some functions at it just after the insert operation and before showing it. What I should have made was to create a function that search for the specific 'newsarticle' after it has been created with the specific attributes

Comment: ***DO NOT DO THIS.*** You do not want to get the *next* ID, because that's wholly unreliable and *will* break your app and/or corrupt your database's integrity. What you want is to get the ID that the previous operation was given automatically via [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php). Eg: 1. Insert a new article. 2. Get the ID. 3. Use that ID in subsequent operations.

Comment: i want to get the next id so when i am going to add new news articles . it saves the photoname+id

Comment: ***DO NOT DO THAT.*** I cannot stress this enough. If you try to guess the next ID [and it *is* a ***guess***] there's no guarantee that there's not another simultaneous request doing the exact same thing, guessing the exact same ID. Preventing this situation is 90% or the reason for AUTO_INCREMENT in the first place.

Comment: any idea how should I name the photos related to the article if i don't use the article id ?

Comment: Read the docs I linked in my first comment.

Comment: Sorry guys. When I asked this question few years ago I wanted to find the next 'newsarticle' object that will be created to do some functions at it just after the insert operation and before showing it. What I should have made was to create a function that search for the specific 'newsarticle' after it has been created with the specific attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18508822/188331). You don't need to do so.

Since you are using auto increment I assume, you don't need to specify the next insert ID when you're performing an `INSERT` query. You can skip the column and MySQL will assign the next ID for you.

For example, you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE samples (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sample_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

When you're going to insert a new record, you just need to execute the following SQL command:

```
INSERT INTO samples (sample_name) VALUES ('Some Location')
```

No need to explicitly specify the value of the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.