# PHP mysqli_insert_id() Function without INSERT

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

PHP mysqli_insert_id() Function

This code print last ID in w3school.com:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age) 
VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");

// Print auto-generated id
echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($con); 

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But I do not want insert anything...I just I want to have last Id,

I try build my own function like this:

```
function getlast()
    {
        $con = connectDB();
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM Articls";
        $result = $con->query($sql);
        $latestID = $result->insert_id;
        disconnectDB($con);
        return $latestID;

    }
```

but seems it's wrong

Comment: `"SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM Articls";`

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821532/get-current-auto-increment-value-for-any-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select the `MAX` id -

```
 $sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM Articls";
```

[MySQL MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html)