# Get last generated id in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an auto-increment column `'id'` . Now I want to echo the last generated id.
I have tried these queries - 
`SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name`
`SELECT id from table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`
`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Above two queries returning the Max Id which is actually the last id generated.
But the problem is suppose if I delete a row where id is 10, then again I insert a row. Then the id would be 11 in the last row, not 10. But these 2 queries are returning the value 9. But I want the value 10.
`LAST_INSERT_ID()` should be used after an insert query which I dont need to do.

How can I get the `id` value of 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'TableName';
```

This was taken from
[Get current AUTO_INCREMENT value for any table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821532/get-current-auto-increment-value-for-any-table)

Comment: well at least you credit the source but um.

Comment: Sorry, never marked anything as duplicate before.  Next time! :)

Comment: its ok, you cant close vote until you have 3k rep, but you should of posted this as a comment