# MySQL auto increment value set to zero

Tags: mysql

Here is a table

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `val` char(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (val)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii;
```

Any idea why is this happening, I expected it to set id to zero in the first query itself

```
MariaDB > insert into mytable set id=0, val="" on duplicate key update id=0, val=val;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB > select * from mytable;
+----+-------+
| id | val |
+----+-------+
|  1 |       |
+----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB > insert into mytable set id=0, val="" on duplicate key update id=0, val=val;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB > select * from mytable;
+----+-------+
| id | val |
+----+-------+
|  0 |       |
+----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB > insert into mytable set id=0, val="" on duplicate key update id=0, val=val;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Any explanation will be appreciated.

Update: I am aware of using AUTO_INCREMENT=0 but the real question here is that query explicitly set id=0, so why it is setting it as 1 in first query. It seems mysql ok to set it 0 in duplicate instance.

Thanks

Comment: is it sequential output?

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: Can you please try, truncating table which will set auto_increment to 0. and confirm it with http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821543/410439. Then execute the above step again.

Answer (score 4):

When inserting a new record, setting an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column to 0 means "generate a new value for this column" ([ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)). Values for `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns start from 1. Thus:

```
insert into mytable set id=0, val="" on duplicate key update id=0, val=val;
```

is equivalent to:

```
insert into mytable set id=1, val="";
```

The second insert you call would create a duplicate key (for the `val` field, **not** the `id` field). This causes the `update` statement to be run, thus updating `id` to zero. The "2 rows affected" message appears because the `on duplicate key update` statement returns 2 in case an existing row is updated ([ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)).

The third `insert` does nothing. Both keys are duplicate, but the existing row doesn't need to be updated because its values are already what you expect them to be. In this case the `on duplicate key update` statement returns "0 rows affected".

Answer (score 3):

By default, the starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.
To let the AUTO_INCREMENT sequence start with another value, use the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE myTabel AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

[Credits](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Comment: I know that. However, the question is that the query explicitly set id=0, then why should it set 1.

Comment: you should have said that in the original question before the edit

Answer (score 1):

The answer about NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO is correct, although a bit incomplete.  There is an option to sql_mode to allow for an explicit value of zero to be entered in an autoincrement field.  By default 0 is treated the same as null.  If you add the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO option, you are allowed to specify a zero value in that field.  I have this in my cnf file:
sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

Answer (score 0):

please check `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` option.

By default, `auto_increment` column cannot be inserted zero value.

If you set NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO on, you can force to input `auto_increment` column zero value.