# How to get current id in INSERT INTO query and sum other number and copy to other column in mysql

Tags: mysql

is there any way to get current auto increment id in INSERT INTO table and sum other number (1000) in mysql and insert to that row with on query;

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2,...) VALUES ('val1', CURRENT ROW ID+1000,...);
```

I can do with 2 query:
first insert row and get last insert id
sum insert id with number
and update row with new value

but I want to do this by just one query if possible.

Comment: So, do you want the auto increment sequence to start from let's say 1000?

Comment: no I want to add some data to auto increment id and save to other column and insert to row

Comment: In my opinion you should never change the primary key in a table, whether is from mysql or other db motor. Don´t make your db logic too complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by declaring a variable and incrementing it with every row, e.g:

```
SELECT val, @i := @i + 1
FROM test, (SELECT @i := 1) a
```

If you want it to start from 1000 and add other data, you can initialise it with 1000.

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17342e/1/0)**

Comment: but i want to add current row auto increment id value to other number, not a single value

Comment: `@i` is current row auto increment id, what is the `other number` here?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
[Get current AUTO_INCREMENT value for any table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821532/get-current-auto-increment-value-for-any-table)

```
SELECT 'AUTO_INCREMENT'
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'TableName';
```

You should be able to wrap this into a function, so that you can drop the function call into your insert query.