# How to get last id inserted on a database in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the last id of my table, I want this to know what is the next number of my counter and to show it to the user, I've tried with the `last()` method but I got this:

```
>>> $trans = Transferencia::last()
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::last()'
```

Is there other way to know this?

Comment: If `ID` is AUTO_INCREMENT, there is no reliable way to know what will be the next one.

Comment: Maybe running `select max(id) from table` get the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current AUTO\_INCREMENT value for any table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821532/get-current-auto-increment-value-for-any-table)

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT **is not a counter** and there is **no way** to know the next value before insert. You just **shouldn't**  show to the user anything like this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

4 Ways to Get Last Inserted Id in Laravel :

Using `insertGetId()` method:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId([
 'name' => 'first' 
]);
```

Using `lastInsertId()` method:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
  'name' => 'TestName'
]);
$id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```

Using `create()` method:

```
$data = User::create(['name'=>'first']);
$data->id; // Get data id
```

Using `save()` method:

```
$data = new User;
$data->name = 'Test';
$data->save();
```

Comment: Yeah it works when I've inserted an item, but in my case i havent, so i just want to know what is the next id availible

Comment: @Christian on the third approach you have the last `id` then `$id+1` is available

Comment: This is very smart especially the third approach

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> $data = DB::select('SELECT id FROM transferencia ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
```

NVM

Comment: This approach should never be used because in the concurrent environment it will obviously return incorrect results

Answer (score -1):

You can use [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function. Try this:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO yourTableName;
```

Answer (score -1):

After save, $data->id should be the last inserted.

```
return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'last_insert_id' => $data->id), 200);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code:

```
$data['password']= md5($request->password);
    
   $customer_id= DB::table('customer')
            ->insertGetId($data);
    echo $customer_id;
```

Answer (score -2):

As I get you right, you want to know which id will be on next insert.
If there is **AUTO_INCREMENT** primary key in table, you can get next value of that key using query:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
AND TABLE_NAME = "TABLE_NAME"
```

**But it's not recommended** to show user his ID before inserting, because it can be changed from other user's session.

Comment: This approach should never be used because in the concurrent environment it will obviously return incorrect results

Answer (score -3):

This can be the best answer:

```
$trans = Transferencia::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)->first();
```

And use `$trans->id`.

Comment: This approach should never be used because in the concurrent environment it will obviously return incorrect results