# How can i select data stored in a database with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

the problem i am facing is i want to read a value that is auto incemented and used, my database takes the following design:

```
|   id   |   category   |   image   |
|   13   |    paper     |    0      |
```

id is auto_incremented, what i want to do is generate the id and use it as the value in image and then upload a file which has his name as the number stored in image, in this example image will be changed to 13 and the file will have the name of 13.jpg.
I started my code by doing this `mysql_query("INSERT INTO category (category,image) VALUES ('$name','$default_item')");` $name is written by the user and $default_item is always zero, what i want to do is change the image to equal id using update and upload an image like this 
`$image_name = '$id' . '.jpg'
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "../images/category/" . $image_name);` 
Where $id is the id in the database

Comment: Why dont you just auto increment image as well? You dont need it to be a string

Comment: I have been able to find the solution of what i needed on my own, Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using auto increment id as the image name.
I will suggest generating a unique name of the image and insert that name in the database and use that name for uploading the image as well.
Use below code to create the image name

```
$uniquesavename = time().uniqid(rand());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO category (category,image) VALUES ('$name','$uniquesavename')");

$image_name = $uniquesavename . '.jpg'
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "../images/category/" . $image_name);
```

By this way user uploaded image will always have a unique name.

Try this and let me know if you face any problem

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections and doesn't work on latest PHP version.

Comment: `$image_name = '$uniquesavename' . '.jpg'` have you tried printing `$image_name`? What does it look like?

Comment: Yeah I know that I was focusing Marjory on problem that guy is facing.
I think so that guy is also trying on older version of PHP
And sorry my bad for not focusing on SQL injection concern

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted as correct,  Sourabh proposed  him an standard approach to store the  images with unique name everytime, (he can use current timestamp for unique combination of name) . According to me it looks good , Upvoted the  answer. Ideally you should not consider auto increment field value to name images.

Comment: @DineshNagar Thanks for supporting the answer

Comment: @MalekSalameh Great to learn that you enjoy the answer. StackOverflow Community Rules encourage members to click an UpVote in such situation, so do not hesitate to reward the value you have found here. This is how this eco-system works

Answer (score 0):

A few things to be mentioned:

You should not use `mysql_query` anymore. Use `mysqli_query` instead. mysql_* is deprecated and has been removed in the latest PHP version.

Secondly: Never use user generated content in an SQL query directly. Use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Otherwise your website is vulnerable to SQL injections.

About grabbing the auto increment value - see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821532/get-current-auto-increment-value-for-any-table).