# Getting the auto incremented id in return of my POST request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to create a team and POST it to my database through the REST service i created, which is working. 
BUT i need the id in return becuase i have to add it in another POST request, so what is the best way to get auto incremented id in return? am i missing some easy solution?

```
/*Post Base Request */
function postAjax(url, data, success) {
    var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(
            function(k){ return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]) }
        ).join('&');

    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) { success(xhr.responseText); }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(params);
    return xhr;
}

/* Funtion used onClick "create team" */ 
function createTeam(){
    var teamToSend = {
        teamName: document.getElementById('name').value
    }
    const convertTomemberIdString = JSON.stringify(teamToSend);
    postAjax('https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc/teams',convertTomemberIdString, function(data){ console.log(data);})
    console.log(`${status}`);
}
```

Comment: There's no "ajax way" to do this; you have to [determine the id on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821532/get-current-auto-increment-value-for-any-table) and add it to your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Have it returned from your server as a response to this request.
2. Maintain a counter variable, and increment it when the request is successful. (Not persistent as you'll lose the value on page refresh)

Comment: i think solution 2 would make sense in my situation, but how do i get the incrementet  id in response of my call? :/

Comment: Your server side code (java/php/node/python/.net etc.) has to be written accordingly for that.