# How to get last auto-incremented value using JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the last auto-incremented value. It works fine from the SQLyog and command prompt but when I use the same query using Spring JdbcTemplate like this:

```
String SQl1="SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
int sales_id=jdbcTemplateObject.queryForInt(SQl1);
System.out.println("returned sales_id is"+sales_id);
```

it returns 0 rather than the expected last auto-incremented value. How can I get the expected value ?

Comment: this is a mysql issue, not a java one. Did you do any inserts at all? what "Select Max(id)" gives you? have you checked that?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125385/last-inserted-id-from-specific-table

Comment: off course i am inserting value before retrieving the row , max(id) is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You probably use a connection pool in Spring JdbcTemplate.

If yes, your driver may use one connection to make the insert, but another different one for the last_insert_id query.

To force using the same connection, start a Transaction before inserting, and commit it after the last_insert_id query.

Comment: i am doing both the things in the same method consecutive statements how the connection object will be different and i am not using the connection pool anyways.

Comment: why don't you try a transaction to be sure? even if consecutive, this doesn't mean they will be served from the same connection if you used a pool. Are you sure you are not utilizing the default pool?